# Something is wrong with my if-statement?

Tags: powershell, if-statement

a confusing question.

```
$msg = 'http://www.bla.de'

$match = $msg -match '^(.*)".+?":(\S+)\s*(.*)$'
$match_linkalone = $msg -match '^(.*)(http://|https://)(\S+)\s*(.*)$'

$match
> False
$match_linkalone
> True

if($match -eq "True" -and $match_linkalone -eq "False")
    {echo 'if';}
        elseif($match_linkalone -eq "True" -and $match -eq "False")
            {echo 'elif';}
                else
                    {echo 'else';}
> else
```

But if I do it like that

```
$match = 'False'
$match_linkalone = 'True'

if($match -eq "True" -and $match_linkalone -eq "False")
    {echo 'if';}
        elseif($match_linkalone -eq "True" -and $match -eq "False")
            {echo 'elif';}
                else
                    {echo 'else';}
> elif
```

I really don't understand this...

When `$match = False` and `$match_linkalone = True` is defined via `-match`, then it should run into my `elseif` statement. But it goes to `else` and I don't know why... But when I manually put text into the two variables it works.

I'm working on PowerShell

Comment: It really is not self-explaining. A confusing question...But if i do it like that... I really don't understand !????!?!? What is your question?

Comment: when $match = False and $match_linkalone = True is defined via -match, then it should run into my elseif statement. But it goes to else and I don't know why... But when I manually put text into the two variables it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables `$match` and `$match_linkalone` contain boolean values, but you're comparing them to strings. In a comparison like that PowerShell [automatically converts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) the second operand to a type matching the first operand. Empty strings become `$false` when converted to boolean, non-empty strings become `$true`.

Basically your expression is evaluated like this:

```
$match -eq "True" -and $match_linkalone -eq "False"
$false -eq $true -and $true -eq $true
$false -and $true
$false
```

Change the second operands to boolean values:

```
if ($match -eq $true -and $match_linkalone -eq $false)
```

or (better yet) remove the comparisons entirely, since your variables already contain boolean values:

```
if ($match -and -not $match_linkalone)
```

and the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

First, some notes about regular expressions:

1) Capturing groups are slower than non-capturing ones, so using e.g. `(?:.*)` instead of `(.*)` is more optimal unless you really need capturing groups.

2) `http://|https://` is equal to `https?://`. Also unescaped slashes are allowed in PowerShell but I'd still use `\/` instead of `/` for various reasons, including compatibility with tools like regex101.com.

---

Now the answer. When `$foo` is a boolean (and `-match` operator always returns a boolean), using constructs like `$foo -eq "True"` is a terrible idea. Not because it won't work (you *could* make it work by writing something like `$foo.ToString() -eq "true"`) but because it's inefficient, unmaintainable and error-prone. Just don't do that! Here's what you want:

```
$msg = 'http://www.bla.de'

$match = $msg -match '^(.*)".+?":(\S+)\s*(.*)$'
$match_linkalone = $msg -match '^(.*)(https?:\/\/)(\S+)\s*(.*)$'

if ( ($match) -and (! $match_linkalone) ) { 
    Write-Output 'if'
}
elseif ( ($match_linkalone) -and (! $match) ) {
    Write-Output 'elif'
}
else {
    Write-Output 'else'
}
```

Output:

```
elif
```

Comment: Thank you! Also the regex101.com-page is brilliant!